# Mirroring application screen using Miracast

Tags: applications, miracast

How do I cast only an application and not whole screen when connected to miracast?

Comment: Miracast is a technology to mirror your screen. AFAIK a restriction to a single app is not supported.

Comment: Put the phone in expanded/immersive mode and enable screen pinning. There you go. I agree with Robert though.